# Javascript delay after increase range in loop to download images from server

Tags: javascript

I have 1 array with thousands link image like this

```
let imageList = ["http://img1.jpg", "http://img2.jpg", ...];
```

I want to loop over the **imageList** and delay after 20 times (n times) increase index like

```
for(let i = 0; i <= imageList.length; i+=20){
  // with i from 0 -> 20
  // do download image from server
  downloadImages(0,20) // [start, end]
  // delay 5s to prevent server timeout because request many times

  // with i from 20 -> 40
  // do download image from server
  downloadImages(20,40)

  // continue delay 5s

  // .... try to finish
}
```

Comment: Is the downloadimage function an async function? Does it return a promise?

Comment: @TheAlpha93 Yes, I used this package from npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-downloader

Like 
for(let i = 0; i <= imageList.length; i++){ download.image(options).then().catch(err => )       }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try smth like this:

```
const imageList = ['***'];

downloadImages(imageList)
  .then(/* done */)
  .catch(/* error */);

async function downloadImages(images) {
  for(let i = 0; i + 20 <= imageList.length; i += 20){
    const n20images = imageList.slice(i, i + 20);

    await fetchImages(n20images);
    await delay(5);
  }
}

function fetchImages(images) {
  return Promise.all(
    images.map(image => /* fetch(image) or smth else */)
  )
}

function delay(seconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000))
}
```

Comment: I can't say I'm a fan of a function named `downloadImage` (singular) which takes a parameter `images` (plural)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [modulus operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

```
let imageList = ["http://img1.jpg", "http://img2.jpg", ...];

for(let i = 0; i <= imageList.length; i++){
  if (i % n == 0) //n is number of images to start delay
  START_YOUR_DELAY_HERE
  downloadImage(20); //20 is number of images you want to download
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async` and `setTimeout` to achieve this:

```js
let downloadImage = async url => {
  console.log(`Downloading ${url}`);
  
  // Simulate a download delay
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 500)));
}

let downloadAllImages = async (imageUrls, chunkSize=20, delayMs=2000) => {
  
  for (let i = 0; i < imageUrls.length; i += chunkSize) {
    
    console.log(`Downloading chunk [${i}, ${i + 20 - 1}]`); 
    
    // This `chunk` is a subset of `imageUrls`: the ones to be downloaded next
    let chunk = imageUrls.slice(i, i + 20);
    
    // Call `downloadImage` on each item in the chunk; wait for all downloads to finish
    await Promise.all(chunk.map(url => downloadImage(url)));
    
    // Unless this is the last chunk, wait `delayMs` milliseconds before continuing
    // (Note: this step may be poor practice! See explanation at bottom of this answer)
    if ((i + chunkSize) < imageUrls.length) await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delayMs));
    
  }
  
};

// Create an array of example urls
let imageUrls = [ ...new Array(100) ].map((v, n) => `http://example.com/image${n}.jpg`);

// Call `downloadAllImages`
downloadAllImages(imageUrls)
   
  // Use `.then` to capture the moment when all images have finished downloading
  .then(() => console.log(`Finished downloading ${imageUrls.length} images!`));
```

Note that if you implement `downloadImage` correctly, so that it returns a promise which resolves when the image is downloaded, it may be best practice to forego the timeout. The timeout is a heuristic way of ensuring not too many requests are running at once, but if you have a fine-grained sense of when a request finishes you can simply wait for a batch of requests to finish before beginning the next batch.

There is an even more efficient design to consider (for your further research). To understand, let's think about a problem with this current approach (which I'll call the "batch" approach). The batch approach is incapable of beginning a new batch until the current one completes. Imagine a batch of 20 images where 1 downloads in 1ms, 18 of them download within 5ms, but the final image takes 10+ seconds to download; even though this system ought to have the bandwidth to download 20 images at once, it winds up spending 10 entire seconds with only a single request in progress. A more efficient design (which we can call the "maximal bandwidth approach") would maintain a queue of 20 in-progress requests, and every time one of those requests completes a new request is immediately begun. Imagine that first image which downloads in 1ms; the moment it finishes, and only 19 requests are in progress, the "maximal bandwidth approach" could begin a new request right away without waiting for those other 19 to finish.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation !!

Answer (score 1):

I use async/await, for of and chunk from lodash for this kind of situation. It'll make the requests in groups of 20 for not flooding the server

```
let i = 0
const imageListChunks = _.chunk(imageList, 20)
for await (const chunk of imageListChunks){
    const chunkPromises = downloadImage(0 + i*20, 20 + i*20)
    const chunkResp = await Promise.all(chunkPromises)
    i = i + 1
}
```

If you need more delay to let the server breath you can add a setTimeout with another await to slow it more

Comment: I don't personally like the design of a `downloadImage` function which takes a range of indices (indicating multiple images). A function named `downloadImage` in the singular should download a single image. And why not pass a url instead of the index of a url?

Comment: I'd prefer it in the way you say, passing the chunk of urls directly as downloadImages(chunk) but I did it in the other way for respecting the unknown downloadImage function of the OP

Answer (score 0):

Set some offset

```js
let offset = 0

for (let i = offset; i <= imageList.length; i += 20) {
  downloadImage(offset, offset + 20) 
  offset += 20
}
```